# Handle deserialisation errors and other exceptions separately

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Using spring-cloud-stream from spring-cloud Hoxton.SR12 release with Kafka Binder.
Boot version: 2.5.2

Problem statement:

- I would like to handle deserialisation errors by pushing them to a poison-pill topic with no retries.
- Handle any other exceptions by retrying and then pushing to a parkingLot topic.
- Do not retry ValidationException

This is my error handling code so far:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ErrorHandlingConfig {

    @Value("${errorHandling.parkingLotDestination}")
    private String parkingLotDestination;

    @Value("${errorHandling.retryAttempts}")
    private long retryAttempts;

    @Value("${errorHandling.retryIntervalMillis}")
    private long retryIntervalMillis;

    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            container.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer parkingLotPublisher) {
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(parkingLotPublisher, new FixedBackOff(retryIntervalMillis, retryAttempts));
        seekToCurrentErrorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(ValidationException.class); 
        return seekToCurrentErrorHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer parkingLotPublisher(KafkaOperations bytesTemplate) {
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(bytesTemplate, (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(parkingLotDestination, cr.partition()));
        deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.setHeadersFunction((cr, e) -> cr.headers());

        return deadLetterPublishingRecoverer;
    }
}
```

I think what I have so far should cover the retryable exceptions being pushed to parking lot. How do I now add in the code to push failed deserialisation events to poison topic?

I want to do this outside of the binder/binding configuration and at the container level due to the outstanding issue of not being able to send to a custom dlqName.

I could use a ErrorHandlingDeserializer and call `setFailedDeserializationFunction()` on it that would contain a function that sends the message onto poison topic. Should I do this using a Source binding or raw KafkaOperations? I also need to work out how to hook this ErrorHandingDeserialiser into the ConsumerFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Hoxton with Boot 2.5? The proper cloud version for Boot 2.5.2 is `2020.0.3`.

The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` already considers `DeserializationException`s to be fatal. See

```java
    /**
     * Add exception types to the default list. By default, the following exceptions will
     * not be retried:
     * <ul>
     * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
     * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
     * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
     * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
     * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
     * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
     * </ul>
     * All others will be retried.
     * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
     * @since 2.6
     * @see #removeNotRetryableException(Class)
     * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public final void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes) {
```

The `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` (without a function) adds the exception to a header; the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` automatically extracts the original payload from the header and sets as the `value()` of the outgoing record (`byte[]`).

Since you are using native encoding, you will need two `KafkaTemplate`s - one for the failed records that need to be re-serialized and one for the `DeserializationException`s (that uses a `ByteArraySerializer`.

See

```java
    /**
     * Create an instance with the provided templates and destination resolving function,
     * that receives the failed consumer record and the exception and returns a
     * {@link TopicPartition}. If the partition in the {@link TopicPartition} is less than
     * 0, no partition is set when publishing to the topic. The templates map keys are
     * classes and the value the corresponding template to use for objects (producer
     * record values) of that type. A {@link java.util.LinkedHashMap} is recommended when
     * there is more than one template, to ensure the map is traversed in order. To send
     * records with a null value, add a template with the {@link Void} class as a key;
     * otherwise the first template from the map values iterator will be used.
     * @param templates the {@link KafkaOperations}s to use for publishing.
     * @param destinationResolver the resolving function.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(Map<Class<?>, KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> templates,
            BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition> destinationResolver) {
```

> I also need to work out how to hook this ErrorHandingDeserialiser into the ConsumerFactory.

Just set the appropriate properties - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer).